# el in view is undefined in testing backbone

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, backbone.js

I would like to test my view from backbone view. but I got problem, I try to obtain the element of my view using `this.$el`, the result is empty. when I check the `this.el` the result is `undefined`

when I try to search it using `$('#container')` it is exist and when I run it, it also works. The tag is exist,
here is my view code

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/setting.html',
  'js/service/Config'

  ],function($, _, Backbone, settingTemplate, Config){
    var settingView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: $("#container"),
      initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
      },
      render: function(){
        data = {}
        var compiledTemplate = _.template(settingTemplate, data);
        this.$el.append(compiledTemplate);
        this.delegateEvents();
        DroneConfig.getAll(function(obj){
          $('input[name=url]').val(obj.url);
          $('input[name=repo]').val(obj.repo);
          $('input[name=hostname]').val(obj.hostname);
          $('textarea[name=api_key]').val(obj.api_key);
        });
      }
    });
    return settingView;
});
```

and here is my test code:

```
    define(['js/view/settingView','text!templates/setting.html'], function(SettingView, texts){
  describe("Setting View", function() {
    it('render successfully', function() {
      $('body').append(__html__['app/js/test/test.html']);
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var x = new SettingView();
        x.render();
        expect($('#setting').html()).to.not.be.empty;
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Do you get any idea why is this happening? I even try to add `$(document).ready(function(){})`. thanks

Comment: you'll want to pass a DOM element into the construction of the instance `new SettingView("<div></div>")` and that div will become your `el`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that `$('#container')` is a function call so your code is equivalent to this:

```
var $el = $('#container');
var settingView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $el,
  //...
});
```

That means that your code will be looking for `#container` when your `Backbone.View.extend` is executed. Apparently there is no `#container` element when that happens so you end up with an `undefined` value for `el` when Backbone tries to un-jQuery-ify the `el` you've supplied.

The easiest solution is to leave the jQuery stuff to Backbone and just use a selector for `el`:

```
el: '#container'
```

Then Backbone will consult the DOM when it needs to build [`$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el) and you should have a `#container` by then.